# ASP.NET Can't Perform Operation on file because it is being used by another process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, cryptography, sha256

I have searched this site for solutions as to why the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Unfortunately, they all seem to have answers very specific to their problem (like email attachments). So, I thought I would post here and maybe be able to get some help with my problem. The end goal with this block of code is just to get a sha256 hash of the file and save the file as such on the disk.

```
string hashedfile1name="";
string hashedfile2name="";
FileStream fs = null;
HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA256Managed();
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    try
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        fs = File.OpenRead("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        hashedfile1name = hash.ComputeHash(bytes).ToString();
        File.Delete("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);

        Label1.Text = "File name: " + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + " - " + hashedfile1name;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You have a file open for read and you are trying to delete it.  Put a `using` around the open and read, then delete outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you dispose the file after reading it - that is close the steam:

```
using (fs = File.OpenRead("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    hashedfile1name = hash.ComputeHash(bytes).ToString();
}
// Now you can delete it
File.Delete("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It worked and is deserving of the correct marker. Also though, when I savas the file with hashedfile1name, the file is getting saved as System.Byte[], why is this?

Comment: Oh wait nvm I fixed it with this: hashedfile1name = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(bytes));

Answer (score 0):

You must Close() file stream before delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the FileStream before deleting the file.